# Build JSON from a very complex JSON Schema in Java

Tags: java, json, recursion, jsonschema

I have a complex issue here and some advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Essentially I have a complex JSON schema that looks something like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://example.org",
    "$id": "http://example.org",
    "title": "schema title",
    "description": "description",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "description": "description",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
                "name1",
                "name2"
            ]
        },
        "storage": {
            "description": "description",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": "200",
            "maximum": "500",
            "default": "200",
        },
        "domain": {
            "description": "description",
            "type": "string"
        },
    },
    "if": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "const": "name1"
            }
        }
    },
    "then": {
        "if": {
            "properties": {
                "version": {
                    "const": "version1"
                }
            }
        },
        "then": {
            "properties": {
                "cpus": {
                    "description": "description",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "minimum": 1,
                    "maximum": 8
                },
                "memory": {
                    "description": "description",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "minimum": 1,
                    "maximum": 32
                },
            },
            "required": [
                "cpus",
                "memory"
            ]
        },
        "else": {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "version": {
                        "const": "version2"
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "cpus": {
                        "description": "description",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "minimum": 1,
                        "maximum": 8
                    },
                    "diskSize": {
                        "description": "description",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "minimum": 250,
                        "maximum": 1000
                    },
                },
                "required": [
                    "cpus",
                    "diskSize"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "else": {
        "if": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "const": "name2"
                }
            }
        },
        "then": {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "version": {
                        "const": "version3"
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "diskSize": {
                        "description": "description",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "minimum": 100,
                        "maximum": 500
                    }
                    "memory": {
                        "description": "description",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "minimum": 1,
                        "maximum": 28
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "diskSize",
                    "memory"
                ]
            },
            "else": {
                "if": {
                    "properties": {
                        "version": {
                            "const": "version4"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "then": {
                    "properties": {
                        "cpus": {
                            "description": "description",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "minimum": 1,
                            "maximum": 28
                        },
                        "memory": {
                            "description": "description",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "minimum": 1,
                            "maximum": 64
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "cpus",
                        "memory"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to build a JSON object using this schema in java. Every property in the schema is inside of a map that I have access to, so I can quite simply just get the property from the map and add it to a JsonNode object that I am building. Every property under the initial "properties" object is easy to retrieve, I can just get a list of them and then get each one from the map.

The complexity lies in the if/then/else part of the json schema. The only way I can see to find which property I need is to first build the initial part of the json from the first "properties" object and then have some sort of quite complex recursive algorithm that goes into every if/then/else statement and compares the value of the property being evaluated and then returns a list of the properties I need to get from the map. I have looked around online for a library that can build Json from a Json schema in java but haven't found anything that can deal with the complex if/then/else statements.

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be I understand it wrong, still, are you trying to build json schema like you pasted in your question?
If yes, build the sample java object maintaining the hierarchy of the child object and convert it to json using jackson

Comment: No, the goal is to build instance data from the schema above.

Comment: @user404 Yes, sorry if it wasn't clear, I have something like the Json schema above but need to use that to actually create a Json object from it

Comment: Try to work with a simple Json schema/object, this documents may help https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html